# Missing *.ts files (due to `npm link` ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular5, tsc

I have this import statement in an Angular5 project:

```
import {plugins, SCECodeGenType} from 'sce-plugins/code-generation';
```

this resolves to this path on my filesystem:

```
/Users/.../suman-chrome-extension/node_modules/sce-plugins/code-generation/index.d.ts
```

When building the app with `ng build -w`, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ../sce-plugins/code-generation/index.ts Module build failed: Error: /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/sce-plugins/code-generation/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:662:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/sumanjs/suman-chrome-extension/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>  @ ./src/app/shared/services/lang.service.ts 14:24-62  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I believe it's because I am using `npm link` to link the `'sce-plugins'` project for local development.

I see some issues with using `npm link` with Angular5 projects here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3875

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8677

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9376

anyone know how to fix?

**Update:**

It does not seem to have do with `npm link` perse, or symlinks. If I simply copy the local directory over to `node_modules/sce-plugins`, I get the same damn error. *Yet*, if I `npm install` sce-plugins into node_modules then I do *not* get the error. Very strange, seems like it has to do with angular-cli, not NPM.

Comment: even if I use `'sce-plugins/code-generation/index'`, I actually still get the same error, weird

Comment: I am using `npm link` to include the `sce-plugins` code, but `sce-plugins` is in my dependencies array too though

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So after reading this Github issue again:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284

I made this change in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
  "defaults": {
    "build": {
      "preserveSymlinks": true //   <<<< add this
    },
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
    }
  }
```

and now, given that `preserveSymlinks` flag and the include field in my `tsconfig.app.json` file:

```
 "include":[
    "./**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/sce-plugins/**/*.ts"
  ],
```

I can now symlink `'sce-plugins'` into my main project, instead of manually copying the files. It's possible that you won't need the `"include"` field at all, although I found that if I removed the `"include"` field, that it wouldn't work.

Comment: I beleive this has changed to `projects -> [project] -> architect -> build -> options -> preserveSymlinks`

Answer (score 13):

In Angular 6 "angular.json" file it's required to put "preserveSymlinks" under "options"
Example:

```
"defaults": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/ConsoleClient",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue while migrating my app from Angular 5 to 6, fix I have applied:

**Added entry of missing file in `includes array` of tsconfig.app.json(ATTENTION: filename is not tsconfig.json)**

Also, make sure that the path you missing file you mention is relative to the 
`tsconfig.app.json`

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a case-sensitive typo in the url of an `import`.

The 'stack trace' of the `ng build` output won't (or should I say might not) point you to the correct place. In my case, I did a global search in Visual Studio for the filename (excluding the `.ts`) and found a reference to the model definition file that was:

```
import { ItemsUsedEntry } from '../models/itemsUsedentry.model';
```

instead of

```
import { ItemsUsedEntry } from '../models/itemsusedentry.model';
```

This was easy to pick up in the Visual Studio global 'Find' window, by scanning all the results for my search on `itemsusedentry.model`.