# npm test fails after upgrade from angular4 to angular 5 "test.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-upgrade

I upgraded my app from angular4 to angular 5 following the steps mentioned here: https://update.angular.io/

I am able to run ng-serve , ng build etc without any issue.

But ng test (npm test) is failing with error:

> \src\test.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation.
>   Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include'
>   property.

I tried doing enough google and solving this issue but none of them seems to be working.

As suggested here,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798373/2754029
I tried to add the config in angular-cli.json and tsconfig.json but that doesn't work.

Can anyone please help me here. Let me know if you need any more info in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that's because `ng test` uses `tsconfig.spec.json`, instead of `tsconfig.json`. Check your `tsconfig.spec.json` and that your `test.ts` is listed in `files` section.

You can see / change which tsconfig to be used at following section of `angular.json`.

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "YOUR_PROJECT": {
      "architect": {
        "test": {
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json", // <---- See here
            "karmaConfig": "src/YOUR_PROJECT/karma.conf.js"
```

See https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#default-app-project-files for more information. Hope it helps.